# (bash) how can i pass a float varibale to if conditional

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement

I am trying to pass this composed variable with a float value:

```
j=1
DA1=178.2929838483883283
if (( $(bc <<< "$((DA$j)) > 150") )) && (( $(bc <<< "$((DA$j)) < -150") ))
then
    D="T"
fi
```

But I get:

```
178.2929838483883283: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2929838483883283")
```

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `x > 150 && x < -150` will be false for all values of `x`.

Second, I notice a common pattern in your questions:
using dynamic variable names with a numeric suffix.
That's very tricky, hard to read and error-prone,
when a much better, simpler and safer alternative exists: arrays.

Rewriting the above code using Bash arrays:

```
DA=()

j=0
DA[0]=178.2929838483883283
if (( $(bc <<< "${DA[j]} > 150") )) || (( $(bc <<< "${DA[j]} < -150") ))
then
    D="T"
fi
```

I replaced the `&&` with `||` in the condition to give it a chance to ever be true.

Comment: thank you, but i need the numerical counter associated

Comment: @Another.Chemist I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: i would like to evaluate $DA$j, not to evaluate the value in an array

Comment: I can see that, but why? From what I've seen so far, you could change your approach to work with arrays instead. Everything will be simpler, cleaner, better, there is no downside, so why wouldn't you go for it?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, your error is self-explanatory:

```
178.2929838483883283: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator \
(error token is ".2929838483883283")
```

You cannot make a comparison using the `((...))` arithmetic operator and a floating point number. Note, you number:

```
178.2929838483883283
```

**note the error:**

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2929838483883283")
```

The `(( ... ))` evaluation has no idea what to do with `".2929838483883283"` because math in bash is *integer* math.

The precise problem is with:

```
$((DA$j))
```

That triggers the error:

```
178.2929838483883283: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator \
(error token is ".2929838483883283")
```

before anything is ever passed to `bc`.

To intentionally run afoul of BASH FAQ006, you can create a variable holding the combined `DA#` and use indirection to access the value, but this isn't a recommended solution, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

j=1
DA1=178.2929838483883283

foo="DA$j"  ## create a variable to allow indirection

if (( $(bc <<< "${!foo} > 150") )) || (( $(bc <<< "${!foo} < -150") ))
then
    D="T"
fi

echo "D=$D"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash compare.sh
D=T
```

Comment: Your option is to multiply `178.2929838483883283` by `1000` or so and then make a comparison between `178292` and `150000` ignoring the remaining decimal places (or whatever precision you need). You can use *parameter expansion with substring removal* to chop off the trailing `.stuff`.

Comment: `bc` just returns `1` or `0` for a boolean statement, so this isn't a problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I apologize, the comparison is attempted by `bc`, but the result is the radix remains. The problem must lie in the substitution because `if (( $(bc <<< "178.2929838483883283 > 150") )); then echo "greater"; fi` works.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - what part are you referring to? `$((DA$j))` was the cause of the error?

Comment: I withdraw my objection.